# Extracting/Exporting contacts in GoogleApps for Education directory

Tags: google-contacts, export, google-workspace-for-business

I don't see a way to export the contacts in Google Apps four Education directory via Google's older/newer layout of contacts.google.com. If there is no such option, Is there any way to extract all contacts displayed in that page by capturing the text data in that page so that I can at least get the required data in a text file?

Answer (score 1):

## On the older Google Contacts

1. Click the directory
2. Click on the checkbox dropdown and select All
3. Click on Import to My Contacts

## On the new Google Contacts

Add the contacts that you found in the Directory to My Contacts.

1. Click Directory
2. Click on one contact. A toolbar will be shown including a checkbox. Click it to select all the contacts.
3. Click Add to contacts

Comment: Hi Ruben. Thanks for the reply. The thing with older Google Contacts layout is that it displays large number of directory contacts in multiple pages so there is no way to select all and add to my contacts list. Then the problem with the newer contacts UI is that even though it's displaying every name in one page there is no select all option. What should I do now?

Comment: @JennySheryl: I updated my answer.

Comment: Regarding the older contacts setup, since I have more than 250 people in my directory list therefore  choosing 'All' from the tick box dropdown doesn't work since the max number of contacts that can be viewed in a page is 250. Then in the newer UI there is no tickbox appearing as you described. Please refer the images for better understanding: http://imgur.com/a/WB2ZC